# Efficient way to calculate 3D matrix multiplication using numpy

Tags: numpy, matrix, optimization, matrix-multiplication, numpy-ndarray

How can I efficiently write and calculate this multiplication using numpy:

```
 for k in range(K):
    for i in range(SIZE):
       for j in range(SIZE):
          for i_b in range(B_SIZE):
             for j_b in range(B_SIZE):
                for k_b in range(k+1):
                   data[k, i * w + i_b, j * h + j_b] += arr1[k_b, i_b, j_b] * arr2[k_b, i, j]
```

For example:

```
SIZE, B_SIZE = 32, 8
arr1.shape -> (8, 8, 8)
arr2.shape -> (8, 32, 32)
data.shape -> (K, 256, 256)
```

Thank you.

Comment: What's the relationship between `k` and `8`?

Comment: Off hand it looks like `einsum` or `matmul` could do it; at least there are `+=` and `*`.  But the mapping among the 6 iterators is complex (and require too much work :( ).

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Numba** for such kind of non-trivial case and **rework the loops** to use efficiently the CPU *cache*. Here is an example:

```py
import numba as nb

@nb.njit
def compute(data, arr1, arr2):
    for k in range(K):
        for k_b in range(k+1):
            for i in range(SIZE):
                for j in range(SIZE):
                    tmp = arr2[k_b, i, j]
                    for i_b in range(B_SIZE):
                        for j_b in range(B_SIZE):
                            data[k, i * w + i_b, j * h + j_b] += arr1[k_b, i_b, j_b] * tmp
```

If you do this operation once, then you can **pre-compile** the Numba code by providing the types of the arrays. If `K` is big, then you can **parallelize** the code using `@nb.njit(parallel=True)` and use `for k in nb.prange(K)` rather than `for k in range(K)`. This should be several order of magnitude fater.